# Change working directory for a task or all tasks in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know that you can change the working directory for a script in Azure DevOps pipelines:

```
- script:
  workingDirectory:
```

I would like to do the same for a task, because we are using a mono repository so we have several pipelines. Each one needs to run only the root directory of a specific project in the mono repository.

```
// Do this in specific directory
- task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
           versionSpec: '16.x'
           displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

This task it's node installer task, it doesn't make sense to specify a working directory and this is the reason why the option it's unavailable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops

If you want you can install the node with command line and not with the above task, in the command line task you can specify a working directory.